# How to change the default data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server (using SSMS V18.7) and I am checking out the Import Data feature to import an Excel worksheet. When I checked the data type of the auto-created table, I noticed that the default string type is `nvarchar(255)`, which overkill for my needs since many of the columns are just Yes/No and I also just need the ASCII character set and I don't want to waste the extra 1 byte/character. Is there a way to change the default data type to `varchar` instead?

Thanks

Comment: `nvarchar`  is the correct default, in my opinion; it'll handle *any* characters in the source. If the setting doesn't match your requirements then change it as you go through the dialogues. You'll be changing the length, precision and scale anyway, so changing the data type too is little extra.

Comment: Data types are specified by what the excel driver thinks it should be. warning: you are in for a world of pain importing excel because the driver often gets it wrong, and can change between runs depending on the data in the sheet (which causes SSIS to fail). Regardless nvarchar(255) is fine for importing data. If you want to do this properly, you  import your data into a staging table with "forgiving" data types like this, then you have another process that goes through and for example changes Yes to a Y in the final table

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to live with this I guess...